# How to reference custom Java class in Fusion Solr Javascript Index Stage?

Tags: solr, lucidworks

In Fusion's Javascript Indexing Stage, we can import Java classes and run them in the javascript such as this :

```
var imports = new JavaImporter(java.lang.String);
with (imports) {
    var name = new String("foo"); ...
}
```

If we have customized complex Java classes, how to include the compile jar with Fusion so that the class can be imported in Javascript Indexing Stages for use?

And where can we store configuration values for the Javascript Indexing Stage to look up and how to retrieve them?

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
var imports = new JavaImporter(mycompany.com.custompkg.SomeParser);
with (imports) {
    var some_config = ResourceManager.GetString("key");
    var sp = new SomeParser(some_config); ...
}
```

Regards,
Kelvin

Answer (score 2):

Starting in Fusion 4.x The API and Connectors started using a common location for jars i.e. apps/libs . This is a reasonable place to put custom jars but the services must be told about the new jars as well.  That's done in two places

```
/jetty/connectors-classic/webapps/connectors-extra-classpath.txt
./jetty/api/webapps/api-extra-classpath.txt
```

Also, index documents can get processed by the api service so even if the jar is only used for indexing, register with both classpaths.  Finally, bounce the services.

Answer (score 0):

Put the Java class file, as a jar file, in $FUSION_HOME/apps/jetty/api/webapps/api/WEB-INF/lib/.

I used this to access my custom class.
var SomeParser = Java.type('mycompany.com.custompkg.SomeParser');